# How to wait for task created by create_task() to complete?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I wrote a test program to try out using `create_task()` that needs to wait until the created task completes.

I tried using `loop.run_until_complete()` to wait for task completion, but it results in an error with a traceback.

```
/Users/jason/.virtualenvs/xxx/bin/python3.5 /Users/jason/asyncio/examples/hello_coroutine.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Test
      File "/Users/jason/asyncio/examples/hello_coroutine.py", line 42, in <module>
    Hello World, is a task
        loop.run_until_complete(test.greet_every_two_seconds())
      File "/Users/jason/asyncio/asyncio/base_events.py", line 373, in run_until_complete
        return future.result()
      File "/Users/jason/asyncio/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
        raise self._exception
      File "/Users/jason/asyncio/asyncio/tasks.py", line 240, in _step
        result = coro.send(None)
      File "/Users/jason/asyncio/examples/hello_coroutine.py", line 33, in greet_every_two_seconds
        self.a()
      File "/Users/jason/asyncio/examples/hello_coroutine.py", line 26, in a
        t = loop.run_until_complete(self.greet_every_one_seconds(self.db_presell))
      File "/Users/jason/asyncio/asyncio/base_events.py", line 361, in run_until_complete
        self.run_forever()
      File "/Users/jason/asyncio/asyncio/base_events.py", line 326, in run_forever
        raise RuntimeError('Event loop is running.')
    RuntimeError: Event loop is running.
```

The test code is as follows. The function `a()` must not be a coroutine,

How can I wait for the task until complete?

```
import asyncio

class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__)
        pass
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def greet_every_one_seconds(self, value):
            print('Hello World, one second.')
            fut = asyncio.sleep(1,result=value)
            a = yield from fut
            print(a)

    def a(self):

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        task=loop.run_until_complete(self.greet_every_one_seconds(4))
        #How can i wait for the task until complete?

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def greet_every_two_seconds(self):
        while True:
            self.a()
            print('Hello World, two seconds.')
            yield from asyncio.sleep(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(test.greet_every_two_seconds())
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How can i wait for the task until complete?

`loop.run_until_complete(task)` in an ordinary function. Or `await task` in a coroutine.

Here's a complete code example that demonstrates both cases:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio

async def some_coroutine(loop):
    task = loop.create_task(asyncio.sleep(1))  # just some task
    await task # wait for it (inside a coroutine)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(asyncio.sleep(1)) # just some task
loop.run_until_complete(task) # wait for it (outside of a coroutine)
loop.run_until_complete(some_coroutine(loop))
```

Comment: or `yield from task` in current case

Comment: @germn:  yes. If OP uses Python version that does not support `await` (<3.5).

Comment: i use loop.run_until_complete(task), but it failure ,

Comment: @user746620: do not call `run_until_complete()` from within a coroutine.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian i use ensure_future(task), i works fine ,but i want to wait for the task until complete, how can i do it ?